# Makefile install target with glob

Tags: makefile

Is there a standard practice for using the `install` utility to install a glob pattern of files without individually executing multiple steps?

I need to retain compatibility with SCO OpenServer 5.0.7 where the `install` utility does not have built-in support for globs.

I'd like to do something similar to:

```
INSTALL = /usr/bin/install
install:
    $(INSTALL) *.4ge $(PROGS)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen projects where several shared libs were moved to install location with a single matching pattern like above.

Besides if all the files(of a particular pattern) are to be moved to the same location it doesn't make sense to move them individually

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I forgot to mention that I need this to work on SCO OpenServer 5.0.7 where the `install` utility does not have support for globs.